# Javascript setTimeout Function Keeps Running

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have an index page for a web app that does a couple of things.  First, it geocodes the user's location and stores it in a variable (i.e. the javascript variable variableToSend below).  Second, it sends that data to mySQL via a php script after 10 seconds (to give the client side time to capture the location).

Everything is working great with one exception - the setTimeout function that I'm using keeps running every 10 seconds and I need to run once and only once on that page.

Here's the code:

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
             setTimeout(function(){
                 var variableToSend = document.getElementById("latLng");
                document.forms[0].submit();
                $.post('html/index.php', {$latLong: "variableToSend"});
                //window.clearInterval(interval);
            }, 10000);
    </script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Your function submits a form, which (probably) reloads the whole page and starts the process over again. It's hard to tell however because you didn't post the HTML of the form.

Comment: Pointy, your exactly right - it does submit the form and thus reloads the page.  Do you have any suggestions to automatically submit the items that I need to outside of a form?

Answer (score 2):

it may help you follow the link [Remove settimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
         var t = setTimeout(function(){
             //do stuff
        }, 10000);

        // sometime later in your code
        clearTimeout(t);
</script>
```